# JSON return error with ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

We are using a ASP app written by an outside vendor.  I am tasked with making a small change to the app however I don't know anything about asp or json.  Through some research I have put this together.  I created a text box on the form and I want to return the client IP address to that text box.  I wrote a function then a controller.  The code for both is below:

The function

```
function processgetip(event) {
    // Within this function, make an AJAX call to get the IP Address
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetIPAddress","getipaddress")', function (ip) {
        // When this call is done, your IP should be stored in 'ip', so
        // You can use it how you would like

        // Example: Setting a TextBox with ID "YourElement" to your returned IP Address
        $("#facility").val(ip);
    });
}
```

The Controller

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Parker_Hannifin.Controllers
    {
    public class getipaddressController : ApiController
{
    public JsonResult GetIPAddress()
    {

        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

        string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
            {
                //return addresses[0]; //
                ipAddress = addresses[0];
            }
        }

        //replace ipaddress with ipAddress
        return Json(ipAddress, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


}
    }
```

I am getting these errors on this line of code:

`return Json(ipAddress, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

The error I get is:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.Json(string,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings) has some invalid arguments.
>   Cannot convert from System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings

If someone could please tell me what they mean and how to fix them I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The second parameter to `Json(...)` is incorrect. You need to return an instance of [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) if you want to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.

Comment: try changing public jsonresult to public actionresult ?

Comment: there is something wrong with your string ipAddress try put a simple string and see if your json work. I think that your string contain some kind of slash or dot something that could cause problem.

Comment: No it didn't change anything still wants to download a file

Answer (score 13):

`Json` in `ApiController` with two parameters has a signature of,

```
protected internal JsonResult<T> Json<T>(
T content,
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings
)
```

`Json` in `Controller` with two parameters has a signature of,

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(
object data,
JsonRequestBehavior behavior
)
```

`getipaddressController` inherited from `ApiController`, but you used Controller method `Json`. Use,

```
return new JsonResult()
{
 Data = ipAddress,
 JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```

If you still want the behavior.

Comment: I replaced This "  return Json(ipAddress, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);"  With " return new JsonResult()
{
 Data = ipAddress,
 JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
}; and the errors are gone.  However when I try to test it IE is downloading a file.  Is that a problem in the function?

Comment: I added the content type to the return code.  Still wants to download a file.  What I don't get is when I remove everything regarding he json code and return to the original code I started with now it wants to download a file as well.