# Severity Code Description Project File Line Supcannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'

code

```
 public JsonResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
                {
                    var pond = DB.Temperatures.OrderByDescending(x => x.WaterTemperature).FirstOrDefault();
                    return Json(new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { id = pond.WaterTemperature, CurrentTime = pond.CreatedDate } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
            }
            return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `Json` method in Web API controller is incorrectly assigned, since [ApiController `Json` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Json%60%601%28%60%600,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings%29) requires `JsonSerializerSettings` as second argument:

```
protected internal JsonResult<T> Json<T>(T content, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings)
{
    ......
}
```

The MVC controller counterpart for [`Json` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json%28System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior%29) is shown below:

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
   ......
}
```

In this case, if the controller class containing `Get` method above extends `ApiController`, you need to change 2 `return Json` statements to `return new JsonResult` as given below:

```
public class ControllerName : ApiController
{
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
            {
                var pond = DB.Temperatures.OrderByDescending(x => x.WaterTemperature).FirstOrDefault();

                // return JsonResult here
                return new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { id = pond.WaterTemperature, CurrentTime = pond.CreatedDate }},
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
        }

        // return JsonResult here
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new { success = false },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

If you want to use MVC controller when returning JSON instead, change `ApiController` to `Controller` class from `System.Web.Mvc` namespace and keep `return Json(...)` there.

Similar issue:

[JSON return error with ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285625/json-return-error-with-asp)