# Why can not return json from web api controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` and want to return json with web api controller,for that purpose write this code:

```
public JsonResult Get()
        {
            var users = GetUsers();
            return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        private List<TestModel> GetUsers()
        {
            var usersList = new List<TestModel>
            {
                new TestModel
                {
                    id = "1",
                    name = "behzad"
                }
            };
            return usersList;
        }
```

but int this line:

```
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
```

get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'  WebApplication1 D:\behzad\project\aspweb
>   api\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Controllers\HelloController.cs    17  Active

Comment: Who down vote me?I'm say beginner!

Comment: return Json(new SelectList(users.ToArray(), "id", "name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     Try this it will work

Comment: @LaxmanGite get that error my friend

Comment: var statelist = _masterService.GetStates().Where(st => st.CountryId == Id).ToList();
            return Json(new SelectList(statelist.ToArray(), "Id", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   make your code like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON return error with ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285625/json-return-error-with-asp)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to all your ASP.Net Web API result return `JSON`. you need a global configuration to make your action comfortable.

for this case, you don't need to call any extra service to resolve `JSON`. follow this:

```
    public List<TestModel> Get()
    {
        return GetUsers();
    }
```

but you need some setting to have it, put below line to the `Global.asax` file and `Application_Start` method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
        var users = GetUsers();            
        return Ok(users);
}
private List<TestModel> GetUsers()
{
        var usersList = new List<TestModel>
        {
            new TestModel
            {
                id = "1",
                name = "behzad"
            }
        };
        return usersList;
 }
```